# Failed to create controller cpu for group

Tags: libvirt, fedora-21

Does anyone know what the error message below mean?

`error: Failed to create controller cpu for group: No such file or directory`

This error only occurs in Fedora 21, in Fedora 20 does not happen.

Comment: What happened to cause the issue? Does it appear on startup or some other time?

Answer (score 0):

I saw a similar issue w.r.t. [OpenStack and CPU pinning](http://specs.openstack.org/openstack/nova-specs/specs/kilo/implemented/virt-driver-cpu-pinning.html). I solved this in F21 by [configuring the "Virtualization Preview" repo](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Virtualization_Preview_Repository), which allowed me to get the latest version of libvirtd (`1.2.13`). I suspect this may be a bug in libvirt.